# Как организовать работу с библиотеками angularjs в проекте?

Tags: веб-программирование, angularjs, модульность

Всем привет! Возможно, очень глупый вопрос, но я всего несколько дней пытаюсь работать с angularJs, это мой первый фреймворк и прошу тапками сильно не кидаться. 
У меня есть проект, который организован (не мной) таким образом:

Есть один общий модуль для всего проекта:

```
var appSdt = angular.module('appSdt', ['sdtConfig', 'authorizationModule',  'ngSanitize']);
```

К этому модулю прикручены все сервисы и фильтры, которые нужны на всех страницах проекта. К нему же пишем директивы. Для каждой страницы - своя. Типа:

```
appSdt.controller('supply', function($scope, $sdtAjax, $sdtObj) {..})
```

Дитектива для страницы "поставки".

И тут возникает момент, когда, скажем для одной из страниц, у меня это калькулятор доставки, нужно подключить несколько дополнительных библиотек. 
В создании модуля уже есть одна из них - '`ngSanitize'`.

А значит, их нужно добавить в `appSdt`, чтобы использовать их в аналогичном примеру контроллере. А значит, что на каждую страницу, подчиненную модулю `appSdt` надо подключить все эти тонны библиотек, которые не нужны им ни разу.

И все это получается немного геморно. Во-первых, повторюсь, куча не нужных библиотек тянем на страницы, во-вторых, мне нужно пройтись по всем 20+ html-файликов, чтобы их подключить, в третьих - если идет совместная работа над проектом, совсем не интересно получается.

Как можно избежать хотя бы чего-то одного? Можно ли организовать какой-то общий файл, который будет подключать библиотеки на все страницы, типа ng-include (если без перехода на php)? 
Или есть какой-то способ адекватный как использовать библиотеки только там, где они нужны, например, создав отдельный модуль, при этом оставив за собой право использовать все сервисы, фильтры и прочую мишуру из модуля `appSdt`?

P.S.: гуглила, но то ли правда, ничего нет, то ли мне пока не хватает навыков чтобы понять и сделать нужные выводы.

P.P.S.: если вместе с тапком пошлете меня на ресурс, где я смогу понять эти моменты, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В Google ищите `John Papa Angular style guide`.  Там будут ответы на все ваши вопросы. После прочтения, 80% отпадёт.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет! Жаль, мой английский пока слишком плох, чтобы быстро въехать в тему на тех оф. ресурсах, что я нашла. =/

Comment: Там ничего сложного. Google Translate справиться